# Ordering in an initialization in C, C++

Tags: c++, c, initialization, initializer-list

Consider the following initializations:

```
/* C, C++ */
int a[] = { f(), g() };
struct { int x, y } foo = { f(), g() };

/* C++ */
struct goo { goo(int x, int y);  };

goo b = { f(), g() };
goo c { f(), g() };    /* C++11 */
goo d ( f(), g() );
```

Is the order of execution `f()` and `g()` in any line specified by C and C++ standards?

Comment: [Obligatory cppquiz link](http://cppquiz.org/quiz/question/107)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In all these two cases

```
goo b = { f(), g() };
goo c { f(), g() };    /* C++11 */
```

the order of evaluation is determined from left to right and all side effects shall be applied before the next initializer.

From the C++ STandard

> 4 Within the initializer-list of a braced-init-list, the
>   initializer-clauses, including any that result from pack expansions
>   (14.5.3), are evaluated in the order in which they appear. That is,
>   every value computation and side effect associated with a given
>   initializer-clause is sequenced before every value computation and
>   side effect associated with any initializer-clause that follows it in
>   the comma-separated list of the initializer-list.

However in C there is other rule

> The evaluations of the initialization list expressions are
>   indeterminately sequenced with respect to one another and thus the
>   order in which any side effects occur is unspecified.

Comment: Come to think of it, I think all but the last are like this in C++11.

Comment: @Vlad: What about first two lines in C++11? The order isn't determined?

Comment: @Corvus  The first expression int a[] = { f(), g() }; satisfies the rule. Take into account that GCC 4,8,2 has a bug. As for the second  expression then is shall not be compiled.:) There is no declarator.

Comment: @Vlad: Sorry for the second expression. I've edit it.

Comment: @haccks: What rule makes it determined for `goo d`, which has no braced init list?

Comment: @BenVoigt; My apologies. I did't noticed that.

Comment: what about initializer list in constructor? are they evaluated in order?

Comment: @texasbruce From C++ Standard: "— Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers)."

Answer (score 11):

> Is the order of execution f() and g() in any line specified by C and C++ standards?

In C, **No**. They can evaluate in any order.

#### C11 6.7.9 Initialization

> The evaluations of the initialization list expressions are indeterminately sequenced with
> respect to one another and thus **the order in which any side effects occur is
> unspecified**,<sup>152)</sup>.

While C++11 says that the order of evaluation is deterministic.

#### 8.5.4:4 List-initialization

> Within the initializer-list of a braced-init-list, the initializer-clauses, including any that result from pack expansions (14.5.3), **are evaluated in the order in which they appear**. That is, every value computation and side effect associated with a given initializer-clause is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with any initializer-clause that follows it in the comma-separated list of the initializer-list.

---

> <sub>152) In particular, the evaluation order need not be the same as the order of subobject initialization.</sub>

Comment: Where are `f` and `g` defined? I don't see it

Comment: @GIJoe; Assume that the provided code is just a code snippet :)

Comment: Could be possibly because the lack of references and the short length of the answer.

Comment: @Manu343726; added the reference.

Comment: @Convus thats not his problem I think. Thats an OP's problem because posting this kind of question tagged for different languages (Possibly thinking that C and C++ are the same language)

Comment: @Corvus; I made it specific. One thing you have to admit is that it is very difficult to answer a question when it is tagged with both C and C++. Believe it.

Comment: But the initializer of `goo d` doesn't have a braced-init-list, so for that one the quoted C++ rule doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2):

No, in C the order of evaluation of the initializers is unspecified:

> (C11, 6.7.9p23) "The evaluations of the initialization list expressions are indeterminately sequenced with respect to one another and thus the order in which any side effects occur is
>   unspecified.152)"
>
> 152) In particular, the evaluation order need not be the same as the order of subobject initialization.

In C++ the behavior is different, and the initializers are evaluated  in the order in which they appear (C++11, 8.5.4p4).

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, the relevant part is paragraph 4 of **8.5.4  List-initialization**

> Within the *initializer-list* of a *braced-init-list*, the *initializer-clauses*, including any that result from pack expansions (14.5.3), **are evaluated in the order in which they appear**. That is, every value computation and side effect associated with a given *initializer-clause* is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with any *initializer-clause* that follows it in the comma-separated list of the *initializer-list*. [ *Note*: This evaluation ordering holds regardless of the semantics of the initialization; for example, it applies when the elements of the *initializer-list* are interpreted as arguments of a constructor call, even though ordinarily there are no sequencing constraints on the arguments of a call. — *end note* ]

So the order of evaluation is **left-to-right**.

**However** note that unfortunately, due to a [bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51253) since at least version 4.7.0, GCC evaluates in the opposite order, **right-to-left**. So if you get any unexpected results, this may be a reason.