# Iterate over base classes of variadic template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

How can I iterate over all base classes of a variadic template class and call a function for each of them.

Here is a minimal example:

```
struct A { void foo() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; } };
struct B { void foo() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; } };
struct C { void foo() { std::cout << "C" << std::endl; } };

template<typename... U>
struct X : public U...
{
    void foo() {
        static_cast<U*>(this)->foo()...; // ??? should call `foo` for all `U`
    }
};

int main() {
    X<A,B,C> x;
    x.foo();
}
```

Comment: Near-duplicate: [Can I tell which template instance class(es) my class is inheriting from?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22882440/2644390)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
struct thru{template<typename... A> thru(A&&...) {}};

struct A { void foo() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; } };
struct B { void foo() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; } };
struct C { void foo() { std::cout << "C" << std::endl; } };

template<typename... U>
struct X : public U...
{
    void foo() { thru{(U::foo(), 0)...}; }
};
```

But if you care about the *order* of calls, watch out for the known gcc bug as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22515948/2644390).

Comment: Good point about the order of evaluation. I believe the array in my answer guarantees the order to be left to right, but I can't quite remember. I know for sure something taking a `std::initializer_list` does.

Comment: @chris Both are guaranteed by the standard. Gcc's bug is only for list-initialization, so your solution works correctly. I usually prefer a struct (like `_do`) that I know will ignore the arguments, though I guess the optimizer will ignore the array as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks. As a side note, you should pick a [different name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: @chris I am aware of these rules, but if I understand correctly, a single underscore is only a problem in the global namespace, and I usually never define anything there (the above was only an example). Right?

Comment: Yes, and even so, do remember the OP might not know them and that they would need to define it in a separate namespace.

Comment: @chris Ok, good point. Changed to my second-favorite name, `thru`. Though most commonly known as `swallow` or `pass`.

Comment: same override `operator,` bug here I believe

Answer (score 9):

You can't normally without C++17's fold expressions. The ellipsis going there is not valid and the ellipsis going after the asterisk would create a list of pointer template arguments. For the appropriate pattern to be repeated, the ellipsis would have to be at the end of the statement, and that doesn't work here. I found [this article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) to be a good resource for pack expansion.

Instead, there *is* a trick for it that doesn't require building up any recursive things:

```
int arr[] = {(static_cast<U*>(this)->foo(), 0)...};
```

This calls each function and then uses the result with the comma operator to produce the needed `int`s. Unfortunately, this might result in an unused variable warning. One minimal way around this is to use a `std::array` (or some class that can be initialized with an initializer list) and cast the result of creating an unnamed one of those to `void` (casting to `void` being a somewhat common technique for preventing the warning in general).

Comment: `{(void)((static_cast<U*>(this)->foo()), 0)...};` -- in case `foo()` returns something that overrides `operator,`

Comment: @Yakk: corrected typo: `{((void)(static_cast<U*>(this)->foo()), 0)...}`;